# Qt - How to associate data with QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I want to associate additional data with each QTableWidgetItem inserted into the table, in order to use that data in future, when it is being clicked on a table item. But that data should not be visible. How can I do that?

Comment: This is one of my biggest complaints against Qt. I've yet to find, in the few months I've been using it, a simple mechanism analogous to data binding in .NET.

Comment: All of Qt's item display classes (trees,tables,lists) are based on Model/View, it's easy to make the backend model anything you like.  There isn't the one click link to SQL you have with LINQ but it's more flexible.

Comment: @Martin I call it "feasible," not "easy"... although I guess it's better than having the data tied directly to the presentation.

Comment: @San Jacinto - perhaps 'sensible' would be a better word! ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`QTableWidgetItem::setData()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) like so:

```
setData(Qt::UserRole, myData); // set
```

Where `myData` is a supported [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) type. You can use `QTableWidgetItem::data()` to retrieve the value that you store.

If you need more than one you can use `Qt::UserRole` + 1, + 2, and so on (`Qt::UserRole` is "The first role that can be used for application-specific purposes.", you can read more about the other types of roles [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)).

If you're storing a custom type that isn't natively supported by QVariant you will need to register your type with the Qt meta-object system. Look at [QMetaType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) for more details on that.

If you wanted to store an integer, for example:

```
QTableWidgetItem* widgetItem = tableWidget->item(row, col); // get the item at row, col
int myInteger = 42;
widgetItem->setData(Qt::UserRole, myInteger);
// ...
myInteger = widgetItem->data(Qt::UserRole);
```

Comment: How can I associate an integer to table item with setData() function?   Should I do following: item.setData(Qt::UserRole, myInteger)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have used this function bu with other Qt Roles and effect was not what I want so I got confused! Thanks!

Comment: If you are adding more than 2 data elements to each table item, it starts to get easier to create a model and use QTableView instead, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

You could derive from QTableItem and provide your own data member, or you could use the QTableView with your own model.

Comment: From my experience this is much more flexible than setData data Qt functions

Comment: Yes but richard's answer is probably easier for a beginner - or if you are just trying to translate some MFC code

Comment: For those reading in the future, QTableItem is now [QTableWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html), and supports subclassing still.