# QTableWidgetItem return item type (pyqt)

Tags: python, qt, types, pyqt, qtablewidget

I'm writing a QGIS plugin using Qt and python (and so pyqt).

In QtDesigner I have a QTableWidget Object and I'm really struggling if there is a way to get the column item type.

For example, in the following table:

[image]

I enter some default parameter that the user can edit. Furthermore the user can add other rows with other values.

I'm wondering if I can get *force* the column data type typing (e.g. float, int, string) and get this information as list (or any other python object) that I can use in the python code.

I did not find something useful in the Qt API.

Do you know if there is a way to do that?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the @rbaleksandar answer I made one more step.

The piece of code is the following:

```
l = []
for i in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
    itm = self.tableWidget.item(0,i)
    l.append(itm.type())
```

But, even if the first line of the table in filled with some number, the resulting list with the QVariant *translated* values is made of zeros:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I found out the QVariant type are associated with numbers (2 for Int, 6 for Double and 10 for Strings) so I expected that `l` was filled with these numbers, so:

```
l = [2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks again

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example that outlines your problem so that other people (including myself) don't have to type a whole application but instead work with your code?

Comment: Do you want to limit what the user can type into a cell?  Like for instance, only allow them to type ints and floats?

Comment: @Brendan Abel, if it is possible yes.

Answer (score 1):

A `QTableWidget` will automatically provide the right editors for the [most common data types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemeditorfactory.html#standard-editing-widgets). But for this to work properly, you must add the values to the table-widget items with [setData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) using the [EditRole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(3, 6, self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Get Value', self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        # populate the table
        data = ['text', 1, 0.25, True,
                QtCore.QDate.currentDate(),
                QtCore.QTime.currentTime()]
        for row in range(3):
            for column, value in enumerate(data):
                item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, value)
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)

    def handleButton(self):
        try:
            item = self.table.selectedItems()[0]
            self.edit.setText('Value: %s, Type: %s' %
                (item.text(), type(item.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole))))
        except IndexError:
            self.edit.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 700, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Fantastic! - I've been looking around for ages trying to find a way to update table items from buttons and getting all sorts of thread-based grief. This is so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the constructors and to be more precise the `type` argument:

```
QTableWidgetItem::QTableWidgetItem(int type = Type)
QTableWidgetItem::QTableWidgetItem(const QString & text, int type = Type)
QTableWidgetItem::QTableWidgetItem(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text, int type = Type)
```

In addition look at `QTableWidgetItem::UserType` (SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579607/1559401) for example)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Anyway, I cannot get a list with numbers of QVariant tyoe, see edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

The `type` argument to the `QTableWidgetItem` constructor is just a way for *you* to distinguish between certain items, it doesn't make Qt display the data any differently or do type conversions or anything like that.  For instance, you could choose to use `type=1001` for `int` cells and `type=1002` for `float` cells, but you're still going to have to do the conversion from `int/float <-> string` on your own.

You can store nearly any data on a `QTableWidgetItem` using the `data()` method and a custom user role (or by just subclassing `QTableWidgetItem` and storing the extra data as an attribute).  But regardless of whatever extra data you store on the item, the item needs to display *something* to the user.  You do this be setting string data on the [display role](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) (this is what `setText()` does), or by using a `QItemDelegate` to manually paint something onto each item cell.

What you want to do is set `int/float` data on items, but display a string representation of them, and also allow users to edit the data.

This is generally done with a [`QItemDelegate`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html).  Here is one way it could be done.

```
MY_DATA_ROLE = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
INT_TYPE = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.UserType + 1
FLOAT_TYPE = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.UserType + 2


class MyFloatIntDelegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent, table):
        super(MyFloatIntDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table = table

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        item = self.table.itemFromIndex(index)
        # This ensures the table is always displaying
        # the int/float value stored in the custom data role.
        if item and item.text() != str(item.data(MY_DATA_ROLE)):
            item.setText(str(item.data(MY_DATA_ROLE)))
        super(MyFloatIntDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = None
        item = self.table.itemFromIndex(index)
        if item:
            # Is this an int item?
            if item.type() == INT_TYPE:
                editor = QtGui.QSpinBox(parent)
                # Set the min/max as appropriate
                editor.setRange(0, 100)  
            # or a float item?
            elif item.type() == FLOAT_TYPE:
                editor = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
                # Set the min/max as appropriate
                editor.setRange(0, 100)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        item = self.table.itemFromIndex(index)
        if item:        
            if item.type() == INT_TYPE:
                editor.setValue(item.data(MY_DATA_ROLE))
            elif item.type() == FLOAT_TYPE:
                editor.setValue(item.data(MY_DATA_ROLE))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        item = self.table.itemFromIndex(index)
        if item:
            item.setData(MY_DATA_ROLE, editor.value())
            item.setText(str(editor.value()))



class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWiget(self)
        self.delegate = MyIntFloatDelegate(self, self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)

        # Creating Items
        vals = [1, 3.5, 6.6, 1.0, 1.0]
        row = 0
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(vals))
        self.table.setRowCount(1)
        for col, val in enumerate(vals):
            item_type = INT_TYPE if isinstance(val, int) else FLOAT_TYPE
            item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item_type)
            item.setData(MY_DATA_ROLE, val)
            self.table.setItem(row, col, item)

        # Getting data
        vals = []
        for col in range(len(vals)):
            item = self.table.item(row, col)
            val = item.data(MY_DATA_ROLE)
            vals.append(val)
```

You could also omit using `type` values and just subclass `QTableWidgetItem` for each different type and do `isinstance()` checks in the `QItemDelegate` instead of checking the `type()` value.  In this case, you could also just store the `int/float` values as `text` data instead of creating the `MY_DATA_ROLE` custom role and convert the text data back and forth to `int/float` values whenever you want the data values.  Of course, that can't usually be done with data more complex than `int/float` values, so using a custom data role (or attributes on subclassed `QTableItemWidgets`) is more flexible and can be used in more situations.

Comment: Wow! I'll give it a try! Thanks